# Detect if someone is coming from a Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtual, virtualization

In other to protect my website, I'd like to know if it is possible to detect if someone is coming from a virtual machine instead of a physical machine.

I searched on the internet and found this way "Virtualization Detection via Screen Dimensions" from this website: https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/i-know-a-lot-about-your-web-browser-and-computer/

I tried but it didn't work.

I'd like to know if it is really possible to detect if someone is coming from a virtual environment, if it is possible, i'd like to know how to start.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't, and even if you could, it wouldn't do anything to protect your website.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information!